# Retain custom added row class after tablesorter implemented

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with the tablesorter plugin and the zebra widget option zebra : `["even", "odd"]`

I have implemented the table sorter plugin for the following html table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed static_table_sorter">
  <tr class="warning">
    <td>Col 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr class="warning">
    <td>Col 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and the jQuery for tablesorter is

```
$('.static_table_sorter').tablesorter({
  // enable debug mode 
  debug: false,
  theme: 'bootstrap',
  widthFixed: true,
  headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', // new in v2.7. Needed to add the bootstrap icon!
  widgets : [ "uitheme", "filter_checkbox", "zebra","stickyHeaders"],
  widgetOptions : {
    // using the default zebra striping class name, so it actually isn't included in the theme variable above
    // this is ONLY needed for bootstrap theming if you are using the filter widget, because rows are hidden
    zebra : ["even", "odd"],
});
```

so on page load the zebra class even & odd appended to the html table row custom class warning. so i could not get the exact result. Can somebody help us how to remove the odd & even class on rows when having class warning

Comment: Looks like you are missing the closing bracket for `widgetOptions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short of figuring out how to do it from the tablesorter initialization, you can always do:

```
$('.static_table_sorter > .warning').removeClass('even odd');
```

after the function call you posted.

Alternatively, don't use `zebra`,even/odd at all, use bootstrap's `table-striped` class instead. (if you're not editing the sass/less then add this css after bootstrap):

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, 
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
 /* css for odd */
}
```

bootstrap doesn't modify the even rows, but you can do

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td, 
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>th {
 /* css for even */
}
```

Comment: But if zebra not used means then on filter the alternate rows will be having the same color

Comment: Even with `table-striped`? are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would fix this using CSS.

Assuming you have something like:

```
.warning { background-color: red; }
```

I'd update it to prevent the even/odd getting in the way like so

```
.warning,
.warning.odd,
.warning.even {
    background-color: red;
}
```